# How to fix scroller speed animation inside intel XDK?

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

When scrolling on my android phone the scroller keeps scrolling even though i stopped scrolling for a while when i remove my finger from the screen. If i scroll with speed and release my finger it looks good. I'm showing a short video from the emulator(i get the same result after build and app preview for android, iphone works good though). Unfortunately u cant see the mouse in this clip but what happends here is that i scroll slow vertically, then i release the mouse, what happends next is that the scroller keeps scrolling abit with a much faster speed aswell(This is what looks ugly and i'd like to fix). I've also tried to use the native scroller in android, it's still the same.

When i open the appframework.ui.js file and temporarly remove the function:

```
jsScroller.prototype.onTouchEnd = function ()
```

It removes the scrolling that happends after releasing the finger/mouse from the screen, however it completely removes it no matter if i stop scrolling with speed or not, which also isn't desirable.

If anyone else has noticed this and know a way of fixing it i would highly appreciate your help, Using appframework + cordova,

//Thanks

[ScrollerVideo](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/0b/5d/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif)

Comment: Do you see this behavior only in the emulator?  Or when you run on an actual device?  What version of XDK are you using?

Comment: I think I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: I have it on actual device aswell, but only in android, not in iOS, im using version 2.2

Comment: if i use ionic instead within the xdk this behaviour is gone, however i'd really like to use the app framework instead. It's clearly something with the code inside the appframework.ui.js file thats causing this it seems

Comment: I'm talking with the AF expert, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks alot, i really appreciate that!

Comment: We've identified the source of the issue and we're working on a fix.

Comment: Okay thats good news, thanks for keeping me updated!